# How to create a Blender shortcut for "Display files as Thumbnails"

Tags: shortcut

When i want to replace a texture for an object, i see my jpg files as a shortlist by default. i can click with my mouse on the thumbnails list to browse my files as thumbnails. but i do this task often , so i need a shortkey for this move.

i have tried to figure out the Python code that is needed for this, but that didn't work out, i don't know why.
i could use some help here.
what do i need to do to get this shortcut ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Preferences->Input->Image->Image_Generic->Open_Image 
 
in the shortcut settings of **Open Image** change the display type to **Thumbnails** :

[image]

Comment: thanks for a fast reply , it sounds logical and it should work , but i did exactly what you said , and i still have to click with the mouse to switch to thumbnails. i saved the user prefs . i have blender 2.73 on MBP2013 Mavericks. i should be more specific about the thumbnails. i don't mind to have the page open up in thumbnails , but i was actually trying to search for a way to toggle between list view and thumbnail view by pressing the short key . if that is not possible , i would be glad to have the possibility to always open in thumbnails. hope to hear soon again , thanks

Comment: you are right ,that was not for switching but for the default window whenyou click Open Image, for switching i'll have to look around a bit

Comment: but i don't mind to have it on thumbnails for a default setting, s long as that would work , i would be happy to keep on using it that way. but that setting didn't work...i will check again if i exactly followed your steps , i think i did.

Comment: i double checked , and it is really not working.
 i saved the prefs afcourse. 
 here is a picture so you can see how it looks. 
http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=vqh013&s=8#.VPPvbdzyBFw

the reason why i asked how to do a shortkey is because i would arrive at the jpg browse window from the UV image editor screen layout. where i use my image replace shortkey to arrive in the textures jpg files list browser.
all these tasks , that is a lot of mouse clicking. hooray for the shortkeys 
 but now how to get it working, i hope to hear from you soon again , thanks

Comment: @elmentor since you are using the 'Replace Image' you should apply these steps to the 'Replace Image' shortcut not the 'Open Image' as i did in the answer

Comment: yes , it worked . you are the best , that saves me a lot of mouse clicks each time i want to replace a texture, thanks a lot !

Answer (score 8):

today i found another solution to get the texture list to view in thumbnails. 
 go to user prefs > file > and check : show thumbnails !

i was actually searching for a toggle between list view and thumbnail view 
 but this solution is working great as well.